# How to read from text file in jQuery

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I have a table with two columns listing the perks associated with the two membership plans available on my site. Next to each perk, I've added a clickable (?): when users click on it, a modal box pops up with extra info about that perk.

I've set up the modal box, but I'm not sure what's the best way to go to populate the box. I was thinking maybe I should read from a text file? How could I do it in jQuery? And how could I select what part of that text file I should read based on the link that is clicked?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your plans info using [JSON](http://www.json.org), for example:

```
[{ "membership 1" : 
    {"name" : "name1", "price": 10}, 
 "membership 2" : 
    {"name" : "name2", "price": 10}
}]
```

You can load JSON files using jQuery with [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

If you have two buttons, one for each membership, you can trigger the '[click](https://api.jquery.com/click/)' method for jQuery:

```
$( "#target" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8026n6a1/1/

Inside that function you can load one membership plan info or another.

Comment: Hi @Sergiodiaz53, I thought about something like that but how do I decide whether to show the "membership 1" or "membership 2" info based on which link was clicked? What should I say in the success function? A little code example would be appreciated! :)

Comment: Thanks but I know how about the click() function. What I asked was what should happen next. In other words, how do I translate the following in code? $( "#target" ).click(function() {
      If #target was Link 1, read values from Membership 1 item in the JSON file.
});

Comment: Your question is how to access to JSON variables? you have to do a little research on your own, man. https://jsfiddle.net/8026n6a1/2/

Comment: You didn't really answer my question but that Jsfiddle set me in the right direction, so I did upvote ;)